# How to properly use PUSH and POP

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, stack, masm, irvine32

I have a code that has 3 procedures, one to get an input from the user, one to display a multiplication result, and lastly one for an error message. I am trying to implement the PUSH and POP operations and get my code in to the stack. It will seem long but it makes sense to me, here it is...

```
.data
    line  BYTE "The answer is ",0
    line2 BYTE "Enter a number",0
    kline3 BYTE Wrong.",0
    int SWORD ?

.code

Val PROC
    call ReadInt
    mov int,edx    
    cmp int, 10000
    jl 1
    jmp end 
    L1: cmp intVal1, -10000
    jg 2        
    call error
    jmp end 
    2: ret
Val ENDP

main PROC
    call Val
    call Val
    imul val, val
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

All this simply does it call to get 2 inputs twice and then call to display the the multiplied result. My question is how do you implement push and pop in to here to have it all make sense?

I would assume that you need to push in the GetValue procedure to put in input in to the stack and then pop it after each call in the main procedure and maybe do the same with the display procedure?

I am just struggling to figure it out so any help would be great!

PS. This code is an asm file in visual studio 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first call to `GetValue` stores its result in `intVal`.  But then your second call to `GetValue` also stores its result in `intVal`, so the first result is forever lost.

Your `MultiplyAndDisplay` function expects one of the operands in `intVal`, and the other operand in `eax`.  So, what you need to do is `push [intVal]` after the first call to `GetValue`, and `pop eax` after the second call to `GetValue`.

<sub>Note that the square brackets in `push [intVal]` are in some notation that actually makes sense, but if I remember correctly the microsoft assembler does not support that notation which actually makes sense, so you might have to code `push intVal` instead, or `push dword ptr intVal`, or something nonsensical like that to get it to work.</sub>

Comment: so i understand the whole push intVal part but can you elaborate on the pop eax and what exactly that does? And this is all that i have to do to concern this code with stacks? you dont actually put push or pop's in the procedures them selves?

Comment: it pops the previously pushed value into the given operand, in this case, eax.  The way you pick your words, "to concern this code with stacks", tells me that you do not yet understand how the stack works, what your code needs to do with it, and even why your code needs to do anything with it at all.  Unfortunately, stackoverflow has a very well defined purpose and direction, and that is for solving very specific problems, not for education over broad subjects such as stack use.  So, I am afraid that you will need to study.

Answer (score 1):

Because your question is tagged MASM, this is a MASM answer:
Your code can be restructured in a way that uses the MASM directive `PROC` with parameters and the [`INVOKE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/73407/using-proto-and-invoke-to-call-a-c-function-from-masm) directive for parameter passing:

```
MultiplyAndDisplay PROC val1: SDWORD, val2: SDWORD
    mov  eax, val1
    imul eax, val2                          ; signed multiply of val1 by val2 
    mov  edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString                        ; Writes the prompt in edx
    call WriteDec                           ; Writes the value in eax
    ret
MultiplyAndDisplay ENDP

main PROC
    call GetValue
    push [intVal]                           ; PUSH firstParam to the stack
    call GetValue
    pop eax                                 ; POP previous param/intVal to EAX
    invoke MultiplyAndDisplay, eax, intVal  ; MultiplyAndDisplay, firstParam(EAX), secondParam(intVal)
    exit
main ENDP
```